# Checksum Utility (File path) does not exist. Verify that the correct file name was given

Tags: xml

I'm trying to browse MD% & SHA Checksum Utility 2.1 and when selecting the file, I receive an error message that says *(file name) does not exist. Verify that the correct file name was given*

What do I do from here?

Thanks.

I tried opening a similar file from a year ago that seemingly is named in the same way and that one opened successfully.